# Keypress is very slow in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have scripted selenium web driver.. It was working fine in IE9. I have upgraded to IE11. The sendkeys command is very in typing characters.  It is entering one by one character and it is really slow.. I definitely did not make any change in the script. Only I upgraded the browser.. Is there any reason for this? Can any one know the resolution please let me know

Thanks

Comment: What `IEDriverServer.exe` are you using, 32-bit or 64-bit, and why are you using that bit-ness driver? My psychic debugging powers tell me you're using the 64-bit executable, which you assumed was correct because you're running 64-bit Windows. With IE 10 and above, this is an incorrect assumption. You should use the 32-bit driver, even if you're on 64-bit Windows. The reasons why are explained in [this blog post](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2014/09/screenshots-sendkeys-and-sixty-four.html).

Comment: I have removed the 2.42.0.0 InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit) and added the 2.51.0.0 driver server 32-bit.. But still facing same issue.. Do I need to change Java version as well?

Comment: Eventhough I have changed the version for InternetExplorerDriver server from 2.42.0.0 to 2.51.0.0. While running the test case I am seeing Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.42.0.0
How to change this to latest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had similar problem with my windows 8, IE11 and webdriver 64bit.
I swapped the 64 bit webdriver to the 32bit one and then the tests just went very fast. (fast response from send_keys which used to be 4-5 secs per key...)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried both 64-bit and 32-bit from 2.51.0. Could not able to resolve the issue..